# Read/Write xBASE (DBASE 3-5 /DBF) files

Tags: java, database, legacy, dbf

Is there any good library for reading / writing  DBF files  in java or any other language ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might give this library a try:

http://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net/

It is open source (GPL) and pure Java.

Comment: nice one!  I'm using it to add to [csvjdbc](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc) the possibility to regard xBase files as possible input.  if you try it out, let me know if it works for you as it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to get to via OleDB provider, such as via .Net, Visual Foxpro would obviously be able to read it natively.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google for dbase and jdbc brought back a number of links for an xbase jdbc driver called StelsDBF. Can't say I've used it or know more than a quick google, but that would be my Java answer.

An alternative Java solution would be to set up an ODBC data source for dbase and then use the [JdbcOdbc bridge](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the JDBC driver from [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf.html). It is type-4 (pure java) and worked well.  My experience with the JdbcOdbc bridge for the same task was quite poor but that may have changed in newer releases.  HXTT's driver is a commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

"any other language"?  like in Python, maybe?

in Python I'm using this one: [dbfpy](http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/).  (not to be confused with pydbf.)
 very usable indeed.