# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, How can I resolve?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I've a problem.
I've got a Database Access (.mdb). I want to connect my java application to the database.

I've done all the necessary in control Panel and into odbc. I set my 32 bit db in it.

Now when I open connection with Database I received only

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

How can I resolve?

P.S. my Code is:

```
public DB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "errore nel costruttore del db");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openConnection(){
        try {
            String url ="jdbc:odbc:mydb.mdb";

            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "errore nell'apertura del db");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the configuration of your ODBC datasource, not on the java side. Test your ODBC datasource to make sure, it works.

Comment: did you create DSN Name with name : mydb.mdb?

Comment: @Bobo87 I googled for your error message. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli