# Java: The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application?

Tags: java, odbc

What is this problem when I connect my java with access???
Error message will display:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

Answer (score 0):

check out,

may be help full to you

[The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application. JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli)

...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef10d625-80d9-4666-b33e-d2f27fde9db5/the-error-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application?forum=adodotnetdataproviders