# how to solve the architecture difference proplem while acessing ms-acess with java without changing the bit version of driver or application

Tags: java, ms-access, architecture, difference

I am using Java(64 bit) and trying to connect with Ms Acess(32 bit)  database.I am following
[this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/433c33/jdbc-connection-to-ms-access/) tutorial.

I had 2 ODBC Data Source option  in my Administrative tool one for 32 bit and other for 64 bit.So i had created my system dsn in **ODBC Data Source(32 bit)** because i was unable to create in 64 bit.

When I executed my java code it gives a runtime error

```
Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

I have searched a bit and found that its because of the bit difference between Ms Acess(32 bit) and Java(64 bit).

**Is there any way by which i can solve this problem without changing the bit version of java or application or without installing any other drivers?**

Is it possible?

I tried similar stack [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli) but dint get any solution apart from changing bit version,I also tried [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx) but that dint work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, the "bitness" of the Access ODBC driver must match the "bitness" of the application that is trying to use it. If your application is running under a 64-bit JVM then you *must* have the 64-bit version of the Access ODBC driver installed if you want to use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

Your other option would be to use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)). It doesn't use ODBC so it doesn't care what version of the Access ODBC driver is installed (if any).