# MS Access Database Connection for JSP page

Tags: jsp, netbeans, glassfish, odbc

I'm using NetBeans 8.0 and i have already created Data source (DNS). its name ackDB.
This is my code (JSP)

```
<body>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:ackDB";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
%>
</body>
```

That will show me an error

[image]

how to fix this. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says your machine architecture doesn't suits with existing driver version. you need to download a different version of `Odbc` driver.. In case of your attempting to connect from `64 bit` OS.

[Learn More](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01028.html) ..

And this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli) may help you