# Converting netbeans java application with multiple classes into .exe

Tags: java, netbeans, exe

I have made a java application on netbeans. Ive tried converting it into .exe with the help of various softwares like exe4j and launch4j. But the problem is, these softwares take only 1 main class. My application has 3. Thus my application doesnt connect to the databsae !

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=search_videos&search_query=exe4j+tutorial&search_sort=relevance&search_category=0&page=

Comment: you can add all classes and you have to select main class

Comment: it didnt work. My application has 3 main classes. exe4j asks to select only 1

Comment: i have 4 classes in which 3 have main method. how am i supposed to select any 1 ? the application won't work then

Comment: in exe4j you should first create a jar file

Comment: my jar file is already created. netbeans itself does that

Comment: what do you mean by `these softwares take only 1 main class`  you program can have only one main class .

Comment: my application has 4 programs out of which 3 have main classes !

Comment: You can define more than one main class in your application. But you have to pick one to launch it.

Comment: my application wont work then, because it wont be able to connect to the drivers and database

Comment: @AnmolKhanna can you post a picture of your folder structure of netbean project

Comment: There can be only one main class used as entry point in a Java program. If you have three main classes and need all of them, you have created three Java applications and should probably create one exe for each of them.

Comment: http://imgur.com/ZDT7Fkh

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen three exe's ?
what do i do now ? obviously i need only one

Comment: See [Using Multiple Main Classes](http://java.about.com/od/netbeans/a/multiplemainclasses.htm). Check your project properties in Netbeans to see which main class is selected in Netbeans and use that one.

Comment: Rewrite your code to start up database etc first. You can't have a jar with 3 main classes that get executed in the correct order. Thus you can't have an exe doing the same.

Comment: @Schaka do i need to write all my code in a single class ?

Comment: You need to re-write those additional main classes in a way that they can be executed by your main-main class. That way, because code is executed sequentially, it will start your servers before starting your application.

Comment: and i have no idea how to do that. newbie here !

Comment: @AnmolKhanna from netbeans do you **manually** run all three main classes ?? even .jar has only one entry point . you can have 100s of classes with main but entry point is just one . ClassName.main(null) // (null String[] ) will work too if you want to call a main from another class

Answer (score 2):

i personally use exe4j

in exe4j when you continue wizard you will get this kind of window

[image]

then you can click green + button to add your excitable jar file and in the genaral area you should specified the main class .in this example `test`

let's say your application name is `newMDIApplication`

in netbeans you have 3 classes

```
 newMDIApplication.class
 newJframe.class
 newJframe2.class
```

when your application start main method of `newMDIApplication.class` get executed .so when you make a jar file you should fill it's main method .

and in that exe4j window you should choose `newMDIApplication` as main class

Comment: @AnmolKhanna ok so you have created a jar file.what happens when you double click it?

Comment: now i am asked to select a main class from the list.
the problem is, all my programs are linked. if i select only one, the databse  will not connect

Comment: okay. i am not making the jar file, netbeans automatically does that.
when i checked the project properties, it showed that application.NewJFrame. was the main method. should i change that now ?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna yes it does but what i'm asking is when you double click that jar file what's happening does it open a gui or nothing happen ?

Comment: The NewJFrame window opens. just like when i run my project

Comment: @AnmolKhanna well that mean your main method is not empty in `newMDIApplication` class. when your programe run your NewJFrame window opens so ,all you need to do is choose newMDIApplication.class as main class .it opens jframe

Comment: i tried that but instead of opening the newJFrame screen which is my login screen, the newMDIApplication screen opens with an error msg saying driver mismatch between dsn and application

Comment: @AnmolKhanna `newMDIApplication` screen?? newframe and newframe2 classes are gui classes .but newMDIApplication.class is not a gui class right?can you tell what is contain inside main method of `newMDIApplication.class`

Comment: all three are gui classes. NewJFrame is my login screen, newMDIApplication is my form where i enter data and NewJFrame2 is a form that gets data from NewMDIApplication to print

Comment: @AnmolKhanna what is the content of main method of `newMDIApplication.class`

Comment: @AnmolKhanna i think problem is that connection failed did you put your libries in the same folder where ur exe exist?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna what is the exact error you are getting when you open exe file

Comment: my login screen doesnt show up. and i get an error saying that there is a driver mismatch between dsn and application

Comment: my login screen is newJFrame.. if i run the main method of newMDIApplication, how will the login screen come ? thus it shows me directly the form page of newMDIApplication with a connection error

Comment: ok @AnmolKhanna do you think netbeans run your all guis simultaneously ? nope  ..how did you make a jar file ?netbeans also ask main class when build jar file.i

Comment: i know that gui's run one at a time. my main method is set to application.NewJframe

Comment: @AnmolKhanna then you should give that class as main class to exe4j .

Comment: is it possible somehow that i call newMDIApplication and newJFrame2 inside JFrame ? so that if i select my newJFrame, the rest are called automatically ?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli

Comment: i know about this issue. but i m getting this error when i run the exe file. my netbeans project runs completely fine

Comment: @AnmolKhanna may be your netbean runs under java 64 but your default system use java 32 .something like that .

Comment: that is not the problem. it uses 64 bit and i have 64 bit drivers

Comment: @AnmolKhanna then why mismatch ?first read that question and answers .try to find your default java verstion

Comment: @AnmolKhanna if you can upload your project[with db] somewhere for instance in google driver so   then i can find the problem

Answer (score 1):

your question is little confusing ..
the Mainclass means the class which contain  *public static void main(String[] args)*

function *void main* is startup of the program. you can initialize your programs in *void main*..

*void main* function will called by JVM when execution has been started..
you can't use use multiple *void mains* because JVM gets confused with it lol

**EDIT**

now i understood your problem

first remove this code from all gui classes ..

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

find and add this code on your class constructor of all Gui classes,  if your class name is NewJFrame then your class Constructor is like this

```
 public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);; // add this code

    }
```

if you  having  Gui classes only .. please add a Java Class and put *public static void main* function on it

```
Class AppleClass{
```

//import your classess here

```
//This is your main class

public static void main(String[] a){ 

//This function will execute first on program startup

//put your look and feel code here (optional, codes given below)

//Here you can put codes for which  GUI you need to show first

}

}
```

you can show GUI by creating its object

**Syntax**

> ClassName  objectname = new ClassName();

ClassName - Name of your GUI Class ;

objectname - any name

for example :

> NewJFrame abc =  new NewJFrame();

look and feel code

```
//  write it inside public static void main


 try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication10.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

make sure these classes are imported

- import java.util.logging.Level;
- import java.util.logging.Logger;
- import javax.swing.UIManager; import
- javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException; import
- javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;

---

**EDIT 3 - Converting into exe**

- Build executable jar , goto run menu-> Clean and Build Project(Project name)
- Download [Launch4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.8/launch4j-3.8-win32.exe/download)  and run it
- set Output exe file location
- set Executable Jar location ( you can find it on dist folder in Project directory)
- goto 'class path' tab uncheck 'custom path'
- goto 'Single Inheritance' tab and uncheck 'Allow only a single......'
- goto 'JRE' tab set min version-1.5.0_45 , max-version -1.8.0_45
- click gear icon and save configration
- click run button

Comment: exe4j asks which main class to select -_-

Comment: how am i supposed to design 3 gui's in one class ?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna no you so misunderstand.do you think your all guis open s simultaneously.there is a one class which open star your programe

Comment: that i know. gui opens one at a time.

Comment: okay @Sajan i tried your way, but after running the exe file i get a architecture mismatch between driver and app.

Comment: load all the resources (arch ,drivers...) and try . or better post source code and sequence of execution of those classes

Comment: @Sajan by your method, all my gui's open at once !
i have to open them one by one ?!

Comment: @Sajan still i get this error. its stlll looking for the main method inside NewJFrame and not my new main class(Say first)    


Error: Main method not found in class application.NewJFrame, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @AnmolKhanna

could you please post source codes of all classes .and explain. program flow.. ?