# The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, laravel

Here is the exception that I am getting:

> ErrorException in DocketController.php line 65: odbc_connect(): SQL
>   error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an
>   architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application,

And here is the `Docketcontroller.php` line number 65:

```
// Localhost
    $dsn = "test2";
    $conn=odbc_connect($dsn, "QA", "QA");

        if (!$conn) {
            exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
            }

    $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$query);
    //odbc_result_all($rs);exit;
    $res=array();
    $fields=array();
    $i=0;
        while($myRow = odbc_fetch_row( $rs ))
        { 
            //echo"<pre>";print_r(odbc_result($rs,1));echo"</pre>";
            $columns= odbc_num_fields ( $rs );
```

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12537390/1206267) It covers why.