# SQL Server 64-bit ODBC Connection to 32-bit Pervasive SQL v10

Tags: sql-server, odbc, 32bit-64bit, sql-server-2016, pervasive

I am using the 64-bit version of SQL Server 2016 Express, trying to connect to a 32-bit Pervasive SQL v10 database. I am setting up a Linked Server in SQL Server via ODBC connection, but I am receiving this error that has given me a lot of pain in the past:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I had a similar issue not long ago trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database, but with help here I was able to obtain the 64-bit ODBC driver for Access. However, there does not seem to be one for Pervasive v10 at all, only for PSQL v11+, which does not help me in this case.

Previous question: [SQL Server Linked Server to MS Access - DSN Architecture Mismatch Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375670/sql-server-linked-server-to-ms-access-dsn-architecture-mismatch-error)

So if anyone has a suggestion for connecting to a 32-bit client from a 64-bit SQL Server installation, when there does not exist a 64-bit ODBC driver for this client, please let me know.

One of the suggested solutions was to use an OLEDB link instead (but no details provided on this, and I'm not sure how it would differ from the linked server I am already trying to create, which is already using OLEDB).

There was also mention somewhere of installing an entirely separate 32-bit SQL Express client, and chaining an additional ODBC link to point to the first one, but I would rather avoid all that overhead if possible, especially since this is a production server that is already running Sage 50 in addition to our own software and web services with SQL Server...

Other details: The client that is built on `Pervasive SQL v10` that I am trying to connect to is `Peachtree 2017` - `Sage 50`. This is all running on `Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard`.

More reading here:

https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=12693&sliceId=1&cmd=displayKC&dialogID=50216&docType=kc&noCount=true&isLoadPublishedVer=&stateId=50217&docTypeID=DT_Article&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23995371/Installing-Pervasive-SQL-Client-on-Windows-2008-64bit-missing-ODBC-Driver.html

Edit:
Thanks for the comments! After further investigation... it looks like this IS actually PSQL v11, not v10. Now, I'm not sure why the 64-bit ODBC driver is not already installed... but I am looking into this now...

[image: 64-bit driver appears to be missing]

Comment: Sorry it is not possible AFAIK. I have a similiar problem with some legacy software. Either get a SQL 2016 Express 32 bit version or a 64 bit ODBC driver.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at upgrading to PSQL v11, v12, or v13.  PSQL v10 went out of support in March 2012 and there have been 3 major releases (as of this writing) since.  All three newer versions hve a 64 bit ODBC driver.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! After further investigation... it looks like this IS actually PSQL v11, not v10. Now, I'm not sure why the 64-bit ODBC driver is not already installed... but I am looking into this now...

Comment: So, to be clear, the install appears to be 32-bit Pervasive SQL version 11. Isn't the 64-bit ODBC driver supposed to work with 32-bit PSQL? Shouldn't it be installed by default if this is PSQL v11? Or would it only come with the 64-bit PSQL install?

Comment: I'm wasting too much time on this, and I can't afford to risk messing up anything on the customer's production database, so I'm just installing an old version of SQL Server Express 32-bit so I can connect to the 32-bit driver. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am having a similar problem in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157076/create-linked-server-in-management-studio-to-sage-50-us-database-using-odbc-data