# MySQL data connection to excel

Tags: mysql, odbc, excel-2013, amazon-aurora

I have a MySQL RDS instance running in Amazon Web Services.  I am trying to create a connection to the database from MS Excel (2013).  I have installed the MySQL ODBC connector and gone through the process of creating a new connection to the database via the Windows Control Panel.  I can confirm that this connection works.

When i attempted to used this connection in Excel by selecting Get External Data, From Other Sources, From Data Connection Wizard.  I then select ODBC DSN from the menu and then select my newly created data source.  Whether i specify my datasource as the datasource name or as the connection string, i get an error "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Unspecified error"

I have workbench installed and am able to connect to the DB via that, there just seems to be an issue with Excel.  I have tried different version of the MySQL connector to no avail.

Another attemp i have made is through choosing the datasource in Excel when selecting From Microsoft Query.  The error message i recieve when i try that is "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

Anyone experience a problem like this and have a possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: The bitness of your DSN and the bitness of your instance of Microsoft Excel are likely different. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895823/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-appli) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that Jerod, through the link i was able to sort out the problem. I will post the complete remedy as an answer shortly.