# How to save a dbf file in groovy or java?

Tags: java, jdbc, groovy, dbf

In one of the questions regarding DBF creation, I found the code below. Did I understand correctly that a DBF file is created here with the names of the columns and the values that will be returned as a result of executing the SQL query? Does println do DBF output? And if everything is so, then how to save the resulting DBF file (name.dbf)?

I'm confused and can't figure it out with DBF. I need to create a DBF file and fill it with values by accessing a function in a SQL package. The second thing is clear to me, I can do it using sql.call and work with ResutSet, but how to save DBF to the computer further is not clear to me.

```
try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String connString="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DefaultDir=E:\\db";//DeafultDir indicates the location of the db
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
            String sql="SELECT * FROM table_name where condition";// usual sql query
            Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: All you need is spend a few hours of time to study the tutorial and practice the examples from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: I don't know English that well. Are there really no examples and what I misunderstood above?

Comment: This code creates no file, but prints the result of an sql query on the console. If you know how to "work with ResutSet", store the result in variables and write their contents into a file.

Comment: @Jörg - In fact it also does not print anything . It's simply written `System.out.println();`

Comment: @Jörg I am familiar with ResultSet, I can save values. How to create a dbf file?

Comment: @Ekz0 - You have used good English in the question and comments. With this knowledge of English, you can not only study the links but also write good articles after mastering them.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I'm familiar with ResultSet, I can access elements, assign them, but I don't understand how DBF is created.

Comment: _I need to create a DBF file_ - there are various tools which provide support for doing that. I think MS-Access (to name one) can [export data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-data-to-dbase-ec7e1708-d6b3-4b11-834b-bf3377b32b1e) to that format. The [dbf tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dbf/info) may also provide some more guidance for this.

Comment: @Ekz0, the code in your question selects data from dbf. if you want to write dbf then you have to insert data.

Comment: i like the library [javadbf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.albfernandez/javadbf/1.11.2). here is an example from tests:  
https://github.com/albfernandez/javadbf/blob/master/src/test/java/com/linuxense/javadbf/DBFWriterStreamTest.java

Comment: @daggett, Look here please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353384/how-do-i-create-a-column-name-in-dbf-more-than-10-characters-in-javadbf-library