# Disable Autocommit for Microsoft dBase driver in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, dbf, dbase

I would like to know how to set autocommit to false for the Microsoft dBase driver, which use is for example presented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079987/613495

Using `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` method throws java.sql.SQLException: `[Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver]Optional feature not implemented`

If such functionality is in fact not supported, then do you know of any other **free** driver for DBFs?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying driver [does not support transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714168(v=vs.85).aspx).  Unfortunately it appears that the only reasonable option is [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf.html).

reference [Read/Write xBASE (DBASE 3-5 /DBF) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277523/read-write-xbase-dbase-3-5-dbf-files)

Comment: Thanks for this info (+1). I still wonder if there is some other free alternatives available. As in my project I cannot use a commercial option.

Answer (score 1):

I was using [KObjects Jdbcwrapper](http://java.net/projects/jdbcwrapper/) project to access DBF files when I needed to fix OpenOffice bibliography (you can look at my source code [here](http://www.dusystems.com/oobf.html)).

It was doing its job for my **reading** purposes well (just one minor encoding related issue that I needed to fix), however I didn't use it for writing.

I can see that writing is supposedly supported too - at least there is some code in `DbaseTable.java`, so chances are it is going to work for you.

It's LGPL.

Comment: Thanks. I would still prefer a driver. Since I have re-coded my program when it got big from the [DANS DBF library](http://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net/) and it is using the aforementioned driver and I can easily execute SQL queries. I also didn't see how would this wrapper support transactions? Thanks anyway (+1).

Comment: DANS library was not available back in 2007 when I was coding my fix :) and most probably jdbcwrapper doesn't support transactions :(