# (Old) DBF files to be processed using javascript

Tags: javascript, dbf

I am trying to use old DBF files. I am not sure what version, what I know is that they were used in an old Access derived program, and that they can be opened seamlessly with Apache OpenOffice (so it is not a weird format with just the dbf extension). It also uses "support" .cdx files, though apparently they are not needed as I can get the content with just the .dbfs.

Rather than using OpenOffice, I would like to process them writing a local web app using javascript.

For that, I would be interested in specification documentation describing the DBF format so thatt I am able to read a stream with javascript. I would appreciate a link to that if someone knows it (my search for these specs has been unsuccessful).

Alternately, some might know a (reputed and well-documented) javascript library that can be used to get streamed data for this kind of files, so that they can be processed programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good collection of links to XBase format specs can be found here I: http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000325.shtml#specs

For a JavaScript library, it may be worth a try to use an existing (Java) library and compile it to JavaScript, see [Read/Write xBASE (DBASE 3-5 /DBF) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277523/read-write-xbase-dbase-3-5-dbf-files) and https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#javajvm

Comment: Very thorough. It is a good suggestion adapting an existing Jaba library, though, for my eeds, and ad hoc parser should be enoug. I guess now I have to find a quick way to make use of binary data and ASCII data in Javascript. By any chance are you aware of anything like this?

Comment: No real experience. I looked around a bit and found that http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/jdataview-read-binary-file.html might serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

DBF files have nothing to do with Microsoft Access. The format was created for good old dBASE II (which ran on MS-DOS) and later adopted by other programs, including some from Microsoft like Visual FoxPro.

I don't know where you searched the format spec but there's a link right at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBase):

- [Xbase ( & dBASE ) File Format Description](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/index.html)

I hope you have lots of spare time ;-)

Comment: I was not even aware of this terminology, according to the link, due to prprietary issues.